# pandas hist method: different behavior if the columns names are all distinct or if there are any duplicated names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
              'a': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
              'b': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1],
              'c': [0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 0.4, 1.2]
              })
```

by running the following

```
df_test.loc[:,["a","b"]].hist()
```

I have the following figure:

[image: Fig1]

whereas if I run:

```
df_test.loc[:,["a","a"]].hist()
```

I have the following figure:

[image: Fig2]

Sometimes I am in need to have the same histogram in two different `Subplots` without repeating it in the same `Subplot` as it happens in the second figure.

In other words, I don't want pandas to plot the orange histograms as shown in the second figure when there are duplicated columns names.
I wish to have the same layout as in the first figure.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You could set both pins to the same color.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
              'a': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3],
              'b': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1],
              'c': [0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 0.4, 1.2]
              })
df_test.loc[:,["a","a"]].hist(color=["tab:blue","tab:blue"])

plt.show()
```

Which therefore results in the same layout: [Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmBVW.png).

EDIT:
If you are not restricted to use `pandas.hist(...)` you could also use `matplotlib.pyplot.hist(...)` instead for more flexibility (`pandas` uses that too for creating the histograms).

```
input_list = ["a","a"]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(input_list))
for i in range(len(input_list)):
    axes[i].hist(df_test[input_list[i]])
    axes[i].set_title(input_list[i])
    axes[i].grid(True)
```

which would result in

[image: Second Version]

Its a bit more lengthy of course, but you have more control over the plots themselves.

Comment: Thanks! There could be a solution, but then I should pass a list whose length depends on the number of duplicated columns. In a dynamic setting, i.e. when the requested columns may vary depending on the user input, that would lead to a cumbersome code. I think the best would be to prevent adding more than one "bar plot" in each subplot, like in the first case I mentioned.